# How to convert Date or Datetime field when some parts are blank; na.omit fails

Tags: r, datetime, na, missing-data, posixct

I have a data set that has dates and times for in and out.  Each line is an in and out set, but some are blank.  I can remove the blanks with na.omit and a nice read in (it was a csv, and `na.strings=c("")` works on the `read.csv`).

Of course, because the real world is never like the tutorial, some of the times are only dates, so my `as.POSIXlt(Dataset$In,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` returns NA on the "only date no time"s.

na.omit does not remove these lines. so the questions are 2

1. Why doesn't na.omit work, or how can I get it to work?
2. Better, How can I convert one column into both Dates and Times (in the posix format) without 2 calls or with some sort of optional parameter in the format string? (or is this even possible?).

This is a sample of the dates and times.  I can't share the real file, 1 it's huge, 2 it's PII.

```
Id,In,Out
1,8/15/2015 8:00,8/15/2015 17:00
1,8/16/2015 8:04,8/16/2015
1,8/17/2015 8:50,8/17/2015 18:00
1,8/18/2015,8/18/2015 17:00
2,8/15/2015,8/15/2015 13:00
2,8/16/2015 8:00,8/16/2015 17:00
3,8/15/2015 4:00,8/15/2015 11:00
3,8/16/2015 9:00,8/16/2015 19:00
3,8/17/2015,8/17/2015 17:00
3,,
4,,
4,8/16/2015 6:00,8/16/2015 20:00
```

Comment: Regarding the second question: What times should these be? `00:00`?

Comment: Regarding the first question. A `POSIXlt` object is actually a `list`. Look at `unclass(DF$In)`. The fix is easy. Use `POSIXct` instead. It's rare that `POSIXlt` is a better choice than `POSIXct`.

Comment: Well, change `as.POSIXlt` to `as.POSIXct` and you are set.

Comment: Regarding the second question, 00:00 or some default. would be fine, an NA that would work would also be fine.  With the lt, can I use the parts of it like a normal POSIX object, i.e. InP$yday? (sorry, noob question, I think my use of LT came from the fact that strptime defaults to LT).  Roland, POSIXct works to make the NAs omittable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "Id,In,Out
                 1,8/15/2015 8:00,8/15/2015 17:00
                 1,8/16/2015 8:04,8/16/2015
                 1,8/17/2015 8:50,8/17/2015 18:00
                 1,8/18/2015,8/18/2015 17:00
                 2,8/15/2015,8/15/2015 13:00
                 2,8/16/2015 8:00,8/16/2015 17:00
                 3,8/15/2015 4:00,8/15/2015 11:00
                 3,8/16/2015 9:00,8/16/2015 19:00
                 3,8/17/2015,8/17/2015 17:00", header = TRUE, sep = ",",
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE) #set this option during import


DF$In[nchar(DF$In) < 13] <- paste(DF$In[nchar(DF$In) < 13], "0:00")
DF$Out[nchar(DF$Out) < 13] <- paste(DF$Out[nchar(DF$Out) < 13], "0:00")

DF$In <- as.POSIXct(DF$In, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")
DF$Out <- as.POSIXct(DF$Out, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")
#  Id                  In                 Out
#1  1 2015-08-15 08:00:00 2015-08-15 17:00:00
#2  1 2015-08-16 08:04:00 2015-08-16 00:00:00
#3  1 2015-08-17 08:50:00 2015-08-17 18:00:00
#4  1 2015-08-18 00:00:00 2015-08-18 17:00:00
#5  2 2015-08-15 00:00:00 2015-08-15 13:00:00
#6  2 2015-08-16 08:00:00 2015-08-16 17:00:00
#7  3 2015-08-15 04:00:00 2015-08-15 11:00:00
#8  3 2015-08-16 09:00:00 2015-08-16 19:00:00
#9  3 2015-08-17 00:00:00 2015-08-17 17:00:00
```

`na.omit` doesn't work with `POSIXlt` objects because it is documented to "handle vectors, matrices and data frames comprising vectors and matrices (only)." (see `help("na.omit")`). And in the strict sense, `POSIXlt` objects are not vectors:

```
unclass(as.POSIXlt(DF$In))
#$sec
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#
#$min
#[1]  0  4 50  0  0  0  0  0  0
#
#$hour
#[1] 8 8 8 0 0 8 4 9 0
#
#$mday
#[1] 15 16 17 18 15 16 15 16 17
#
#$mon
#[1] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
#
#$year
#[1] 115 115 115 115 115 115 115 115 115
#
#$wday
#[1] 6 0 1 2 6 0 6 0 1
#
#$yday
#[1] 226 227 228 229 226 227 226 227 228
#
#$isdst
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#
#attr(,"tzone")
#[1] "GMT"
```

There is hardly any reason to prefer `POSIXlt` over `POSIXct` (which is an integer giving the number of seconds since the origin internally and thus needs less memory).

Comment: Truly wish I could upvote 2 times... That was a great answer (your knowledge is vast.)

Answer (score 2):

You've been given a couple of strategies that bring these character values in and process "in-place". I almost never use `as.POSIXlt` since there are so many pitfalls in dealing with the list-in-list structures that it returns, especially considering its effective incompatibility with dataframes. Here's a method that does the testing and coercion at the `read.`-level by defining an `as`-method:

```
setOldClass("inTime", prototype="POSIXct")
setAs("character", "inTime", 
      function(from) structure( ifelse( is.na(as.POSIXct(from, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") ), 
                                          as.POSIXct(from, format="%m/%d/%Y") ,
                                          as.POSIXct(from, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")  ), 
                                class="POSIXct" ) )

read.csv(text=txt, colClasses=c("numeric", 'inTime','inTime') )
  Id                  In                 Out
1  1 2015-08-15 08:00:00 2015-08-15 17:00:00
2  1 2015-08-16 08:04:00 2015-08-16 00:00:00
3  1 2015-08-17 08:50:00 2015-08-17 18:00:00
4  1 2015-08-18 00:00:00 2015-08-18 17:00:00
5  2 2015-08-15 00:00:00 2015-08-15 13:00:00
6  2 2015-08-16 08:00:00 2015-08-16 17:00:00
7  3 2015-08-15 04:00:00 2015-08-15 11:00:00
8  3 2015-08-16 09:00:00 2015-08-16 19:00:00
9  3 2015-08-17 00:00:00 2015-08-17 17:00:00
```

The `structure` "envelope" is needed because of the rather strange behavior of ifelse, which otherwise would return a numeric object rather than an object of class-'POSIXct'.